# Audio pause/play button in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, audio

I found answer to this problem as given in script below but the issue is how to make it work with @foreach loop querying mp3 data from database

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
var btn_playPause = document.getElementById("btn_playPause");

function losAudio_playPause() {
  var isPaused = losAudio.paused;
  losAudio[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  this.style.backgroundPosition= "0 "+ (isPaused ? "-32px":"0px");
}

btn_playPause.addEventListener("click", losAudio_playPause);
```

```css
#btn_playPause{
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENFH5.png) no-repeat;
  border:none;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<audio id="losAudio" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg">Audio not supported</audio>
<button id="btn_playPause"></button>
```

Comment: What's the problem ? Do you know how to get data from the DB and loop over them in Laravel ?

Comment: Yes I know how to do that

Comment: This is the loop @foreach($ebeats as $ebeat)
                 <audio id="{{$ebeat->beat }}" src="/musicfile/{{$ebeat->beat }}">Audio not supported</audio>
                    <button id="btn_playPause"></button>
                  @endforeach

Comment: This is the js script added at the bottom  <script type="text/javascript">
var audio = document.getElementById("{{$ebeat->beat }}");
var btn_playPause = document.getElementById("btn_playPause");

function losAudio_playPause() {
  var isPaused = losAudio.paused;
  losAudio[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  this.style.backgroundPosition= "0 "+ (isPaused ? "-32px":"0px");
}

btn_playPause.addEventListener("click", losAudio_playPause);
</script>

Comment: Please i need to pass the music file from database into the src but i can't get it right. Kindly help